# Getting to use GitHub

Tags: github, repository

I am very new to `GitHub`. After reading a short introduction, I go my hands on this: https://guides.github.com/introduction/getting-your-project-on-github/ and am trying what is taught.

When reaching the “Push your code to GitHub.com” step, I get this error message: “Request Failed Error Publishing Repository”

What is or what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should comes from the [push section of the tutorial](https://guides.github.com/introduction/getting-your-project-on-github/#pushit)

Double-check your name and GitHub account.

If that still fails, open a command-line, go to your local repo, and type

```
git remote -v
```

If you see nothing,

- go to gitHub.com, create a new empty repo,
- go back to your local folder, and type

  ```
   git remote add origin https://github.com/<yourAccount>/<yourNewRepo>.git
  ```

Then you can directly push, or try again in the GitHub Desktop if that GUI detect the link between your local repo and the remote repo.